# What is the best approach to assign the visibility for multiple controls

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean

OK so i'm trying to clean up my code because it is a mess and what i have is 25 richtext boxes and i want to put their .Visible variable into an array and have a for statement go through and make each false so that the text box doesn't show up what i have tried hasn't worked and i can't figure it out what i have is.

```
bool[] box =  new bool[25];

box[0] = richTextBox1.Visible;
box[1] = richTextBox2.Visible;
box[2] = richTextBox3.Visible;
box[3] = richTextBox4.Visible;
box[4] = richTextBox5.Visible;
box[5] = richTextBox6.Visible;
box[6] = richTextBox7.Visible;
box[7] = richTextBox8.Visible;
box[5] = richTextBox6.Visible;
box[6] = richTextBox7.Visible;
box[7] = richTextBox8.Visible;
box[8] = richTextBox9.Visible;
box[9] = richTextBox10.Visible;
box[10] = richTextBox11.Visible;
box[11] = richTextBox12.Visible;
box[12] = richTextBox13.Visible;
box[13] = richTextBox14.Visible;
box[14] = richTextBox15.Visible;
box[15] = richTextBox16.Visible;
box[16] = richTextBox17.Visible;
box[17] = richTextBox18.Visible;
box[18] = richTextBox19.Visible;
box[19] = richTextBox20.Visible;
box[20] = richTextBox21.Visible;
box[21] = richTextBox22.Visible;
box[22] = richTextBox23.Visible;
box[23] = richTextBox24.Visible;
box[24] = richTextBox25.Visible;

for(int y = 0; y <25; y++)
  {
    box[y] = false;
  }
```

Comment: The box[...] = richTextBoxx.Visible stuff doesn't actually do anything. You're initialising an array only to then rewrite the entire contents before you do something with it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You canot change the `bool` in the array and expect that that changes the `Visible` state of the TextBoxes.

You have to change that property. Therefore you either have to store these controls in a collection or use a different approach: If they are in the same container control (like `Form`, `GroupBox`, `Panel` etc.) you could use  `Enumerable.OfType`.

For example:

```
var allRichTextBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>()
    .Where(txt => txt.Name.StartsWith("richTextBox"));
foreach(var rtb in allRichTextBoxes)
    rtb.Visible = false;
```

Comment: This assumes that there are no other RTBs on the form than the 25 RTBs he want's to manipulate. I already consider 25 RTBs on the same form a WTF, but maybe you should change your query so that the names are taken into account like the OP does in his question.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: I have edited my answer to take only those which start with `"richTextBox"` although that seems almost arbitrary. But maybe that helps OP to use something more meaningful.

Comment: Well, he could name the RTBs that should be handled to a different prefix than the ones that should not be handled. Good approach. I'd go with your answer :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar the reason i got all of those is that i'm just now learning how to use Forms and so i started off by creating a notpad that can have 25 files open at once.

Answer (score 4):

I think, this is what you need:

```
for(int y =0; y < box.Length; y++)
{
    ((RichTextBox)this.FindControl("richTextBox" + (y+1).ToString()))
                      .Visible = box[y];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Booleans are value types, and thus when you assign:

```
box[0] = richTextBox1.Visible;
```

you are only copying the boolean, this is completely independent of the object (referenced by `richTextBox1`) and changing to a different boolean value will only change the content of the array, there is no link to an object to change its property.

The simplest approach – there are others that might suit better but are more complex – is to store the object references in an array and set the property directly:

```
var boxes = new RichTextBox[...]
boxes[0] = richTextBox1;
...

for (int y = 0; y < boxes.Lengthl y++) {
  boxes[y].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox.Visible` is a property and as such returns a *value*. Your array of Boolean therefore contains values as well. Changing this value does nothing to your textbox, because it doesn't know anything of the textbox anymore.

Storing a reference to a value is not possible in C#, so try the following instead:

```
RichtTextBox[] box =  new RichTextBox[25];

box[0] = richTextBox1;
box[1] = richTextBox2;
box[2] = richTextBox3;
box[3] = richTextBox4;
box[4] = richTextBox5;
// ...

for(int y = 0; y <25; y++)
{
    box[y].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your controls inside a asp:Panel then change the visibility of the panel.visible = false.... why over complicate things?

Comment: Why assume this is ASP.NET? Why not consider the possibility that not all the RichTextBoxes can be put into the same panel? etc. etc.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Why not consider they are on seperate pages? Why not consider they are in seperate assemblies? Besides that though C# was a .Net project, so it's a reasonable assumption and in my humble opinion does not warrant a negative vote.

Comment: What if they can be put into the same panel?

Comment: If they could be put onto the same panel, this would be a solution. Still, there is no `RichTextBox` control for ASP.NET. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't get around it, so put it in a separate method and assign them all in one go

```
private void SetVisibilityForAllTextBoxesTo(bool isVisible)
{
    this.richTextBox1.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox2.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox3.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox4.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox5.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox6.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox7.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox8.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox6.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox7.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox8.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox9.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox10.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox11.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox12.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox13.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox14.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox15.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox16.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox17.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox18.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox19.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox20.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox21.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox22.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox23.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox24.Visible = 
    this.richTextBox25.Visible = isVisible;
}
```